# How to add autcomplete to dropdown and then display content depending on user selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to implement an autocomplete dropdown menu on our wordpress site. The functionality should be as follows:

Input box where user can start typing, then once they make a selection from the list, specific content is displayed.

I have it figured out with the functionality of returning the content related to the user selection. (code below)

```
<script>
  jQuery(function($){
  $('.group').hide();
  $('#option0').show();
  $('#selectMe').change(function () {
    $('.group').hide();
    $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
  })
});
</script>


<select id="selectMe" class=".dropdown">
  <option value="option0">Select Your Brand</option>
  <option value="option1">Brand A</option>
  <option value="option2">Brand B</option>
  <option value="option3">Brand C</option>
  <option value="option4">Brand D</option>
</select>

<div id="results">

<div id="option0" class="group">
Generic content as a placeholder until selection is made.
</div>

<div id="option1" class="group">
Content related to Brand A. 
</div>

<div id="option2" class="group">
Content related to Brand B.
</div>

<div id="option3" class="group">
Content related to Brand C.
</div>

<div id="option4" class="group">
Content related to Brand D.
</div>

</div>
```

I'm brand new to any type of javascript or jquery and I am unsure how to make it so they can start typing a word in an input field to show available selections rather than scrolling through a long list in a dropdown menu to find to what they're looking for. (there will be over 200 possible selections in the dropdown)

UPDATE:
I've figured out the autocomplete part by using jquery autocomplete ui

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "Burger King",
      "Chick-Fil-A",
      "Chipotle Mexican Grill",
      "Dunkin'",
      "McDonald's",
      "Panera Bread",
      "Sonic",
      "Subway",
      "Starbucks",
      "Wendy's"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Search your brand: </label><br><br>
  <input id="tags" placeholder="Start typing...">
</div>

  <div class="results">
  This is where I would want the content based on user selection to be shown.
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I went through the autocomplete events but don't understand where I'd put any additional code to show content related to what the user selects in another div.

Any help with this coding would be appreciated!

Comment: [JQuery UI Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) will handle this (the autocomplete part) for you.  Unless you have a specific requirement to implement this logic on your own, I suggest you use an autocomplete widget.  JQuery UI is not the only one...there are many available.  It also sounds like you may be looking for a cascading drop down effect, where the selection from one drop down determines the options available in another drop down?  If that's the case, look at the `OnClose` event in the JQuery UI Autocomplete, and do some googling for cascading drop downs

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I'll look into the Autocomplete widget... I have seen that come up in my research but wasn't sure how it would implement with the requirement of needing to show specific content based on user selection. (like i said.. superrr new to this! lol) I don't need the selection to determine other options in another dropdown, I just need to show specific content based on what the user selects from the one dropdown. Hope that helps clarify!

Comment: displaying specific content based on the user selection is a separate concern from autocomplete.  implement autocomplete, and then work on what displays based on the user's selection.  The `OnClose` event from the JQuery UI Autocomplete will help you.

Comment: I just updated my original question with your recommendation on the autocomplete. on the plus side, that part works beautifully.. on the downside, i have zero idea how to get the second part of this working.

Comment: could you provide a JSFiddle to help you?

Comment: oh! yes of course. https://jsfiddle.net/vqLw9sey/